# Should I add this Android Studio file in gitignore: build/intermediates/dex-cache/cache.xml

Tags: android

I think I need to add the following file to my gitignore:

```
build/intermediates/dex-cache/cache.xml
```

in Android Studio. Should I?

If so, how could I do that?
This is my current gitignore file:

```
# Built application files
/*/build/

# Crashlytics configuations
com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Gradle generated files
.gradle/

# Signing files
.signing/

# User-specific configurations
.idea/libraries/
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/tasks.xml
.idea/.name
.idea/compiler.xml
.idea/copyright/profiles_settings.xml
.idea/encodings.xml
.idea/misc.xml
.idea/modules.xml
.idea/scopes/scope_settings.xml
.idea/vcs.xml
*.iml

# OS-specific files
.DS_Store
.DS_Store?
._*
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
ehthumbs.db
Thumbs.db
```

Comment: Delete `/*/` from your first `.gitignore` line, leaving `build`, and you should be set. Everything in `build/` is output.

Comment: So that file that the question is about SHOULD be added to gitignore? And doing what you told me to will add it there?

Comment: "So that file that the question is about SHOULD be added to gitignore?" -- IMHO, yes. "And doing what you told me to will add it there?" -- yes.

Comment: Thank you, if you add this as an answer I will accept it